# How do I use a users input to determine which array to use?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 11 different arrays with colors for variable names. Each array contains 2-4 rank names, current points, and points needed for next rank. In java I'm using scanner to get user input asking for color name (string). How would I take that input to determine which array to use? Say they're in rank color green how do I use string input green to use array green?

Comment: use if statements, a hashmap, an array of arrays, theres so many directions you could go

Comment: `if (inputStr.equals("green")) //do something` You're going to have to show more examples of your code/your intention to take this farther, because there are a billion different ways this could go

Comment: Have you tried anything? Put some code

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is variable indirection (or some variation depending on the language), and it's not something that should be done in Java (although it's possible with reflection if you just want to watch the world burn).

The sane way to do it would be to use a `Map` instead, which would associate to your colours the arrays you're using (or equivalent lists actually, once again unless you want to make other programmers scream in horror).

Now the thing is I don't see any reason you should keep your arrays as they are. The big problem with them is that they don't contain coherent data : rank names,that should be `String`s, and two kind of points with different meanings, that should be `long` or some other numeric type.

So what I suggest you do is find a way to put these informations in another class, let's say `Rank`. Then you craft a nice `Map<String,List<Rank>>`, which will be so much easier/powerful to use :

```
Rank firstGreenRank = colorToRanks.get("green").get(0);
long pointsNeededToReach = firstGreenRank.getPointsNeededToReach();
long howMuchPointsNeededForSomePlayer = firstGreenRank.howManyPointsStillNeededFor(somePlayer);
colorToRanks.get("blue").forEach(System.out::println); // displays every rank for a colour, assuming you've implemented Rank.toString();
//displays each colour with its associated ranks, still assuming Rank.toString() is implemented.
colorToRanks.entries().forEach((colour, ranks) ->
  System.out.printf("Category %s's ranks : %s%n", ranks.join());
```

If you don't use the power of OOP, there not so many reasons to use Java.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are retrieving the input from the user in a way such as this:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
System.out.println("Enter a color: ");
String inputColor = reader.next(); // Scans the next token of the input as a String.
```

To match the value of `inputColor` with an array, I would suggest using a switch statement.

```
 String[] temp;
 switch (inputColor) {
     case "green":
         temp = green; //the array named "green"
         break;
     case "orange":
         temp = orange; //the array named "orange"
         break;
     //etc.
     default:
         //set temp some default array or an error
 }
```

While I chose a switch statement for implementation, there are so many other ways you could accomplish your goal (if-statements, hash maps, etc, as others have noted).